# Why does Appium python find_element_by_id fails in AWS device farm but works on local?

Tags: aws-device-farm, python-appium

I am able to run my appium python test script on my local appium server. But when I run it on AWS device farm it fails with following error in the log -

[image: erro]
I made sure I provided an empty desired capabilities object to the driver.
Please help me fix this.

TIA.

Comment: Can you post appium server logs from local and device Farm?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I believe I was on python 3.6 and have now switched over to 2.7.x. Things are working.

Answer (score 1):

Switching from python 3.x to python 2.7.x seems to have resolved this issue.